# Gluon Mobile: Unable to scroll to bottom of scrollPane in Android

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I use a `SplashView` to show an EULA when the app is started for the first time:

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="pneContent"  fitToWidth="true" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<VBox id="boxEula" spacing="8" fillWidth="true">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="0" right="16" bottom="16" left="16"></Insets>
    </padding>
    <TextView fx:id="txtEula" id="txtEula" />
    <HBox spacing="24" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button fx:id="btnDecline" text="%button.decline" styleClass="touch-target" />
        <Button fx:id="btnAccept" text="%button.accept" styleClass="touch-target" />
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

`TextView` extends `TextFlow` and adds some convenience methods, but no layout logic. It contains several links which will be opened in a browser. When I navigate back from the browser to the `splashView` I'm not able anymore to scroll to the buttons at the bottom of the scrollPane.

A listener attached to `scrollPane.vValueProperty` showed that the `vMaxValue` of '1' is already reached before the bottom of the scrollPane is showing.

I've tried to update the scrollPane content by:

```
 ServiceHelper.call(LifecycleService.class, s -> s.addListener(LifecycleEvent.RESUME, () -> pneContent.requestLayout()));
```

without success.

```
 public EulaPresenter(SplashView splash, Trigger onEulaAccepted) {
    this.splash = splash;
    this.onEulaAccepted = onEulaAccepted;
}

@FXML
protected void initialize() {
    txtEula.addTextWithLinks(Eula.getText(), 3);

    btnDecline.setOnAction(evt -> ServiceHelper.call(LifecycleService.class, LifecycleService::shutdown));
    btnAccept.setOnAction(evt ->
        {
            dispose();
            onEulaAccepted.start();
        });

    splash.setCenter(pneContent);
    initFab();

    clickedOnScrollFilter = new MouseClickedOnScrollFilter(pneContent);
    clickedOnScrollFilter.activate();

    Listeners.executeOnceWhen(pneContent.layoutBoundsProperty(), () -> !pneContent.isFocused(), e -> Platform.runLater(() ->
        {
            pneContent.setVvalue(0);
            pneContent.setOpacity(1);
        }));
}

private void initFab() {
    fab = new FloatingActionButton();
    fab.setFloatingActionButtonHandler(FloatingActionButton.TOP_RIGHT);

    fab.textProperty().bind(new When(pneContent.vvalueProperty().isEqualTo(pneContent.vmaxProperty())).then(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_UPWARD.text)
                                                                                                      .otherwise(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_DOWNWARD.text));
    fab.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            if (fab.getText() == MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_DOWNWARD.text) {
                pneContent.setVvalue(pneContent.getVmax());
            } else {
                pneContent.setVvalue(pneContent.getVmin());
            }
        });

    splash.getLayers().add(fab.getLayer());
}

private void dispose() {
    splash.getLayers().remove(fab.getLayer());
    fab.textProperty().unbind();
    fab = null;

    clickedOnScrollFilter.deactivate();
    clickedOnScrollFilter = null;
}
```

}

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue? My splash view has a `ScrollPane`, with a tall VBox that has a link on top, and a button at the very end (that needs scrolling). The link uses the `Browser` service, to use the native browser. When I navigate back to the splash view, scrollbar is enabled, so I can scroll to the button and close the splash. What's different in your case? Are you using a JavaFX `WebView`?

Comment: I've updated my question. I can scroll the ScrollPane but not to the bottom. To be more precise, the Hbox containing the buttons can be reached, but as soon as I stop dragging the scrollPane the HBox disappears. There is some more strange behavior concerning the ScrollPane. When it is shown for the first time, it is scrolled to its bottom, i.e. to the HBox. Hence the `Listeners.executeOnceWhen` method.

Comment: I'm using a 'Label' with a 'mouseClickedListener' attached to it as a Hyperlink control. The listener uses the Browser service to open the link.

Comment: I'm using an Hyperlink node, and since in my case it is on the top, it takes the focus, and the scrollpane doesn't scroll to the end. Maybe that's the issue with your scrollpane: the first focusable node is the first Button at the bottom. Can you make a quick test adding a focusable node on top?

Comment: I've changed my Labels for `Hyperlink`s, and now the scrollPane starts at its `vMin` position. But now there is a huge space between the last line of the text and the HBox, and the box is still not reachable when you navigate back from the browser. All these issues seems to be caused by the lines:  `link.setWrapText(true);  link.maxWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract(32))`. When I remove this line everything is fine, but the linktext doesn`t wrap to the next line.

Comment: Can you try adding a listener to `widthProperty()` instead?

Comment: This works when the scrollPane is shown for the first time. Going back to it, produces an additional space between text and hbox, not as big as before about 3-4 lines, but only on Android. On desktop the text overlaps the hbox right from the start. I guess for now I replace the link url with a short placholder text, so I won't need to wrap the text

Comment: Ok, one comment about the FXML files: when using `<View>` as the root container, remove the width/height settings from the plugin. If you don't set them, the view will be adjusted fine, otherwise you are forcing some settings that may be different in your device. The bad news about this is editing the View with Scene Builder.

Comment: ? ScrollPane is the root container of my FXML file. I'm setting it as the center node of the SplashView in my EulaPresenter, and there is no width/height setting applied to it. Could this be causing the weird behaviour?

Comment: Ok, maybe it is not the case. Have you tried removing `fitToWidth="true"` and `fillWidth="true"`?

Comment: Removing `fillWidth="true"` is working a little better. And it is working with the widthProperty binding as well. There is still a small additional gap (on Android) when you navigate back, which will be removed as soon as you start scrolling

Comment: Probably you are facing the known issue on Android, when a native view is dismissed and the JavaFX view doesn&#39;t have time enough to be properly laid out. When you start scrolling a layout pass seems to fix it.